# How to solve IEnumerable<DataRow> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

Can you explain what difference error at parameter value and source?
I try to query at DataTable so need convert to IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> tablecust = datasetcust.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
```

And then query

```
DataRow cust = tablecust
    .Where(x=> x.Field<string>("Name") == "Customer1" 
            && x.Field<string>("Address") == "Karet" )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I got error :

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name : value
```

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get this error? What does `dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count` return? What does `cust == null` return?

Comment: When query. .Where()

Comment: I have asked three questions ;)

Comment: Sory, my connection is not good :) 1. Error when tablecust.Where()  2. dataset.Table[0].Rows.Count == 7893 3. Cust ==null is true

Comment: My third question is useless if the query itself throws an exception because then it's clear that `cust` doesn't get a value and remains `null`. So have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, i have. But i dont know what happen :(

Comment: it's not possible that you get this error in the line `tablecust.Where...`, so you have to use the debugger and tell us what happens. We can't help further without more informations. Maybe it's not really in this line but later where you try to use `cust`.

Comment: How to know to get error? I place my breakpoint at  that line. No empty variable. I guest error when x.Field, but i dont know how.

Comment: There is no way to get this error at `x.Field`. String is a reference type so it works even if the value is `null` or it is `DbNull.Value` . `Field` will return `null` in both cases. If there was no column like `Name` or `Address` you would get a different error. So i guess that you haven't shown the relevant code.

Comment: Wait, i think you'll get this error when the table itself is `null`. Your title "`IEnumerable<DataRow>` Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value" has confused me. Is the exception actually: `ArgumentNullException.Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source`?

Comment: But ds.table[0].Rows.Count > 0

Comment: If i change my code to like this DataRow cust = tablecust.Where(x=> x.Field<string>("Name") == "Customer1").FirstOrDefault(); the result is null. And this DataRow cust = tablecust.Where(x=> x.Field<string>("Address") == "Karet" ).FirstOrDefault(); the result is null.

Comment: I expect that the return is null. Not error, 'value cannot be null'.

Comment: your expectations are right, it's not possible that you get this exception there.

Comment: So, any ideas why i get this?

Comment: No, please post the fullstack trace(including complete error message, line numbers and call stack) and more code, f.e. where you use `cust` in the following lines. Maybe it's also helpful to see how you fill the table(f.e. from database, then show the query).

Comment: Okey.thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because either column (Name or Address) values will be null and you have to handle before comparison.